# is there any method for creating 3D charts in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

I want to make a 3D pie chart in my app but I am finding difficult to find the solution that shows the percentage and name for the area of selected region in the graph.

I am using AnimatedCircularChart and for that the package is:
import 'package:flutter_circular_chart/flutter_circular_chart.dart';

```
 > AnimatedCircularChart(
            key: _chartKey,
      size: _chartSize,
      initialChartData: _quarterlyProfitPieData[0],
      chartType: CircularChartType.Pie,
```

I want the label over the selected region.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this package flutter_echarts: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_echarts

It has the capability of WebGL 3D Charts

See this example:
https://github.com/entronad/flutter_echarts/tree/master/example

[image]

Comment: in this 3d chart cant see tooltip on phone device

Comment: Unfortunately echarts doesn't work on web.

Answer (score -2):

The [Flutter Circular Chart](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_circular_chart) is cool animated chart library, but it is hard to give custom modification such giving label on top of it. 
I Found [Chart Flutter](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/charts_flutter) library is a good alternative for your case. It can create Pie Chart with a custom label. And the best part is you can animate it too. This open source library maintained by Google Team.

Here some example code implementation with Chart Flutter:

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PieOutsideLabelChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  PieOutsideLabelChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  /// Creates a [PieChart] with sample data and no transition.
  factory PieOutsideLabelChart.withSampleData() {
    return new PieOutsideLabelChart(
      _createSampleData(),
      // Disable animations for image tests.
      animate: false,
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.PieChart(seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        // Add an [ArcLabelDecorator] configured to render labels outside of the
        // arc with a leader line.
        //
        // Text style for inside / outside can be controlled independently by
        // setting [insideLabelStyleSpec] and [outsideLabelStyleSpec].
        //
        // Example configuring different styles for inside/outside:
        //       new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
        //          insideLabelStyleSpec: new charts.TextStyleSpec(...),
        //          outsideLabelStyleSpec: new charts.TextStyleSpec(...)),
        defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcRendererDecorators: [
          new charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
              labelPosition: charts.ArcLabelPosition.outside)
        ]));
  }

  /// Create one series with sample hard coded data.
  static List<charts.Series<LinearSales, int>> _createSampleData() {
    final data = [
      new LinearSales(0, 100),
      new LinearSales(1, 75),
      new LinearSales(2, 25),
      new LinearSales(3, 5),
    ];

    return [
      new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
        id: 'Sales',
        domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
        measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
        data: data,
        // Set a label accessor to control the text of the arc label.
        labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales row, _) => '${row.year}: ${row.sales}',
      )
    ];
  }
}

/// Sample linear data type.
class LinearSales {
  final int year;
  final int sales;

  LinearSales(this.year, this.sales);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: It is not 3D chart