# Is there a library for a 3D pie chart in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, 3d, pie-chart

I'm working on an app with Flutter, and the client wants a 3D pie chart. Problem is... Every library that I found only has the classic 2D pie chart. Its like it doesn't exist, in Flutter, the option for a 3D one.

I'm currently using [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter).

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818541/13646430

Comment: Yes, I already saw it, but it doesn't have 3D pie charts. Like every other library that I found, they offer only 2D ones. https://echarts.apache.org/next/examples/en/index.html#chart-type-pie